# jQuery dialog close callback converted to Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this old jQuery dialog function that I'd like to rewrite to work with the Bootstrap modal. Specifically the close callback. It seems (to me) that Bootstrap doesn't have something like this. When I replace it with `hide` function, the modal opens and closes immediately. I'm using Bootstrap v4-alpha.

jQuery

```
jQuery("#myDialog").dialog({
    close: function () {    
    jQuery("#myDialog").html('');
  }
});
```

Bootstrap

```
jQuery("#myDialog").modal({
 // What can I add here to replicate jQuery's close callback?
});
```

Comment: Provide a demo that reproduces problem as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap when you trigger your modals you can attach event listeners.

So when you trigger:

```
$('#myDialog').modal('toggle'); // or 'show'/'close'
```

Use the event listeners instead to attach callbacks

```
$('#myDialog').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Fire a function when the modal opens
})
```

Docs here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events

Comment: I tried this approach before posting my question. When it's written this way the modal closes immediately after it's shown. It would seem that jQuery's close function was stored until the dialog is closed by a separate function. Is this the case, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry  the argument is actually not 'open', it's 'show', try using `$('#myDialog').modal('show');` instead.If it opens and closes immediately it might be due to another function triggering it somewhere just like you said. Try removing the jQuery dialog library too. If you cant find the function use chrome developer tools and in the Sources tab find the function to trigger the modal and add a breakpoint, then go through each function call by pressing the 'Step over next function call' button on the top right. Good luck!